# Replying to twilio message with basic CGI

Tags: python, twilio, cgi

I know you can reply to Twilio with flask, but I am trying to do it using nothing more than CGI. I looked at https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/sms/reply/ and checked the XML they are returning, and I wrote a cgi script on an EC2 server that returns the exact same XML data when run with CURL. But when I try to put my URL instead of the example URL as the Webhook I get the "connection failure" warning. Is there something wrong with just putting "myURL/cgi-bin/program.py" as the Webhook? Or is there something else I am missing here?

I found a few related questions, but no one really seemed to have a good, working solution to this.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? Also, what are the headers that the response returns? You can find out by requesting the URL with `curl --head URL` .

Answer (score 1):

Can you HTTP POST to your URL using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) (or did you change the HTTP method to GET and successfully hit your URL from your web browser? Also, is the returned MIME type correct, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilio-understands-mime-types.

Alan

Comment: I checked and I can reach it via POST and GET requests, and the MIME I copied directly from an example on Twilio's website.